# Mac OS X New Users From Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line

I need to add a new user via the command line in single-user mode.  I reinstalled OS X earlier, and for some reason, it didn't create my user account properly.  Now I can't log in.  So I'm wondering how exactly I can go about creating a new user account without reinstalling everything.

I tried this, but it didn't work: http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/20702/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-5 *much* better answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

...and then reboot normally.  With that file gone, OS X launches its first-run Setup Assistant and (among other things) lets you create a new account.

BTW, the reason `niutil` isn't there has nothing to do with whether it's a server or not -- it's because Apple got rid of NetInfo (its old database for storing local users) in 10.5, and replaced it with a new [XML-based system](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=LeopardServerReview-LocalDirectory).  If you want to do `niutil`-ish things in 10.5, you can either use [`dscl`](http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/) (this is actually a bit complicated in single-user mode because directory services aren't running) or create/edit the XML files by hand.

Comment: You may need to boot into single-user mode (hold down Cmd-S at startup) and mount the filesystem in read/write mode (there will be instructions on screen on how to do so) before you can delete the file, especially if you don't have an admin account at all.

Answer (score 6):

As of 10.10 you can use the sysadminctl command to add a user, in this case prompting for the password and adding them to the admin group:

```
sudo sysadminctl -addUser collin -password - -admin
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030603190314390

Comment: Leopard (non-server) has no nireport or niutil, unfortunately...syntax looks very similar to dscl though...

Comment: That's because the "ni" in those utilities is for "NetInfo", which has (thankfully) been replaced as of Leopard. Collin is on the right track, dscl is the replacement, but using it is not trivial, either. Although I'm sure OS X is designed primarily for GUI addition/manipulation of users, for situations like yours, it would be nice if the process from Terminal were a easier and better documented.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bad idea to install Puppet just for this task, but if you're a puppet user and you want a cross-platform solution:

Create the file, `user.pp`, containing:

---

```
group { 'jenkins':
  gid        => '507',
}

user { 'jenkins':
  ensure     => present,
  uid        => '507',
  gid        => '507',
  shell      => '/bin/zsh',
  home       => '/Users/jenkins',
} 

file { '/Users/jenkins':
  ensure => directory,
  before => User['jenkins'],
}
```

---

and then execute it with: `puppet apply user.pp`.

Note that you should change the username (jenkins) and gid/uid as necessary.

Comment: Not really very practical in most cases, but interesting nonetheless.  And +1 for using zsh.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like if it didn't create your user account correctly you probably need to reinstall again in case other things didn't get set up correctly.